# Android POS accept Google Pay via NFC & Chip

Tags: android, nfc, kiosk, pos, google-pay

I have an Android Kiosk POS that I sell to my clients to accept payments. To accept payments, a USB magnetic swipe card reader is attached to the Android Kiosk (it has a USB port) and on swipe, as soon as the keyboard input comes in, the listening activity parses it and extracts the required card info. We then get a token for the card from Stripe and charge them via Stripe as well. This has been working quite well since we released it.

However, a new need has arisen. That is the need for accepting EMV & Google/Samsung/Apple Pay + whatever NFC payments comes in the future. I just purchased another USB card reader from China that accepts chip + NFC + swipe. I know how to handle the swipe part as it is the same as what I have been doing with the single functional card readers that we use in the field currently.

However, I don't know how to accept the chip and especially the NFC payments. I have Google Pay setup on my phone and whenever I put it near this new card reader, it beeps and types (it is considered a keyboard even though it's not) an 8 digit number. So, I know it detects it and all and generates some number, but I have no idea what this number means. I thought it was supposed to give me the card number and all the way the magnetic swipe gives me the tracks. The same for the EMV part... however, with the EMV part of the card reader, it doesn't even seem to get any input.

I am hoping someone has experience with this type of device with Android and can guide me.

[Sdk documentation I got with device](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mTJsklY_9W9vOA9LCk05dMuxBKRd8fct/view?usp=sharing)

[Picture of the new device](https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/-QQAAOSwMmBVuuiM/s-l640.jpg)

Comment: Just making sure you read this page: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/payments/android-pay

Comment: Yes. That doesn't address my question though.

Answer (score 1):

The number you're receiving on your reader is not the card number number (PAN) - it's a token (sometimes called DPAN) which represents your card, but isn't the same as the card number.

From [Google Pay Merchant Help - How payments work](https://support.google.com/pay/merchants/answer/6345242) (emphasis mine):

> Google Pay does not send merchants their customers' actual card numbers when they pay in shops; instead, Google Pay facilitates a process called tokenisation, in which a token stands in for a customer's actual credit and debit card numbers.
>
> [...]
>
> To make a purchase, a customer taps their mobile device on a point-of-sale terminal or chooses to pay in your mobile app. Google Pay **responds with the customer's tokenised card and a cryptogram which acts as a one-time-use password**. The card network validates the cryptogram and matches the token with the customer's actual card number.

Effectively, this is a security feature to prevent malicious card readers from simply reading and storing the card number from a phone that supports Google Pay, Apple Pay or a similar payment method.

Comment: I thought it would be a tokenized card as well... However, it is the same "token" every single time. Even when I switch cars from Google pay. Also, I tried my Hilton credit card which has nfc built in and that also gives the same number every single time. I highly doubt it would be the same every time even for the same card if it was tokenized. I think it reads the serial number or something if the card because I downloaded some random app on my phone which claims to read nfc cards and the number there device was getting, this app said it was the serial number...

Comment: My best guess is that the reader you have is not correctly following the EMVCo spec for contactless payments. But even if it did, what you're trying to do (reading the card number to then feed into an online payment form) is simply not possible by design with tokens.

Comment: Then what is the way for me to accept Google/Samsung/Apple pay on Android via tap and pay?

Comment: You'll probably want to get an actual credit card terminal that can accept and process contactless payments. Using just an NFC reader is not enough. Many modern credit card terminals can connect to an Android device (usually via bluetooth), so you can probably get one of those if you want to keep your current solution.

Comment: Hmm... Can you recommend such a device that connects to Android.

Comment: I'd avoid mentioning any particular brand here, but if you Google for "credit card terminal android" or "point of sale android", there should be plenty of options.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented an open source EMV payment framework (https://github.com/vicente-da-silva/dcemv). This implements both EMV contactless and contact kernels. There are various NFC drivers. It runs on Android. You could use this for EMV transactions where the card PAN is tokenized or not, but for tokenized cards via HCE, the bank/acquirer you are dealing with would have to integrate with Samsung/Apple/Google Pay in order to pass them the token and have it translated back to the original PAN.